# Drawing data in socket.io

Tags: canvas, socket.io, paperjs

I have googled for some solutions and tried implement them but some of them didn't work and some of them was complicated for me. I tried to implement some solutions all leads to failure.

I am a newby here and want to learn how to implement socket.io with paper.js on easiest example possible. Complicated stuff just confuses me. I'll write my sample code here.

Client side:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="paper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Define inlined JavaScript -->
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="Canv">
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

var scope = new paper.PaperScope();
scope.setup(Canv);



var path;


    function onMouseDown(event) {
        path = new Path();
        path.strokeColor = 'black';
        path.add(event.point);

}


    onMouseDrag = function(event) {
        path.add(event.point);


    }



</script>



    <canvas id="Canv" width="900" height="500"
    style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:13%;border:1px solid;"> 
              </canvas>     
</body>
</html>
```

And Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
connect = require('connect');

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
var socket = io.listen(app);
```

Please improve it so it will send drawing coordinates... I looked in many tutorial but didn't got it.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a old question.. Here is a tutorial: http://www.12devsofxmas.co.uk/post/2012-12-28-day-3-realtime-collaborative-drawing-with-nodejs